# Bruteforcing a seed with 24 words of a unknown order

Tags: mnemonic-seed, bip

How much time would it take to brute force a seed that we know all of its words but also that is completely shuffled? I ask this because the old Trezor model asks for seed in a shuffled way but still all the words can be seen. So if a malicious software would intercept all the words, in what time could the adversary crack the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends a little bit if all words are independent. If yes the will be `24! = 620.448.401.733.239.439.360.000` permutations of the words. Assuming that you computer can check 1 billion permutations per second (which is is way too optimistic as this would assume that a signature / public key could be computed within one clock cycle which he can't) this would mean that your computer still would need `620.448.401.733.239` seconds which is `19674289` (19.6 million) years as the absolut minor / lower bound.
This estimation however does not take into account technological breakthroughs in computing hardware which could very well happen in that time frame (:

Comment: Sorry but wouldn't this be a vast over estimation? Assuming the checksum alone is possible in every combination (divide by 16) but every combination cant have a valid checksum with the given word list (I dont think?) Unsure how to calculate lol.

Comment: before checksum computation you would still have to generate each permutation. so if I estimate checksum check with one clock cycle or also add the signature / pubkey computation doesn't make too much of a difference (in my opinion) I think the point is that it is not feasible to brute force this.

Comment: How about if I have the wallet address?

Also, if we account that we can use the checksum hack to further reduce the keyspace by 256?

We would have !24 possibilities \ 256 **minus any improvement gained from having the wallet?

Just brainstorming.